# how to optimize performance of nfs running inside Strongswan ipsec transport on 10Gb network

Tags: nfs, ipsec, strongswan

Host1: Ubuntu 18.04
Host2: Freebsd 11.2

Here is my situation... I have 2 hosts on a 10G lan that have Strongswan IPsec transport configured between them to secure nfsv3.  (Yes, I know nfsv3 is old and i should move on, but reasons...). As soon as I set the MTU to 9000 for the last link in the chain (host2 interface, 10G switch interface, other 10G switch interface, host1 interface) my nfs mount seems to hang.

I believe I have 2 problems to solve.  1st, once my ipsec connection is up, my performance, as measured through iperf3, drops from 9.4Gb/sec to ~800Mb/sec.  2nd, the NFS mount can't do anything once the tunnel is up and all related interfaces are using mtu 9000.

So, what should I do to increase my ipsec performance over a 10G LAN and what is wrong my NFS?

Host1 is mounting host2 via NFS using this fstab entry:

```
host2:/exports/share /mnt/storage nfs    
_netdev,nofail,noatime,nolock,tcp,actimeo=1800  0 0
```

Since this a 10G lan I updated the kernel options for both systems to be more 10G lan optimized.

Host1 kernel tunings in /etc/sysctl.d/10-mychanges.conf

```
# Maximum receive socket buffer size
net.core.rmem_max = 134217728

# Maximum send socket buffer size
net.core.wmem_max = 134217728

# Minimum, initial and max TCP Receive buffer size in Bytes
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 134217728

# Minimum, initial and max buffer space allocated
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 65536 134217728

# Maximum number of packets queued on the input side
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 300000

# Auto tuning
net.ipv4.tcp_moderate_rcvbuf = 1

# Don't cache ssthresh from previous connection
net.ipv4.tcp_no_metrics_save = 1

# The Hamilton TCP (HighSpeed-TCP) algorithm is a packet loss based congestion control and is more aggressive pushing up to max bandwidth (total BDP) and favors hosts with lower TTL / VARTTL.
net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=htcp

# If you are using jumbo frames set this to avoid MTU black holes.
net.ipv4.tcp_mtu_probing = 1
```

Host1 ipsec.conf

```
# ipsec.conf - strongSwan IPsec configuration file

# basic configuration
config setup
        charondebug="ike 4, knl 4, cfg 4"

conn %default
        ikelifetime=60m
        keylife=20m
        rekeymargin=3m
        keyingtries=1
        keyexchange=ikev2
        mobike=no

conn host-host

        left=192.168.0.4
        leftid=@host1
        leftcert=/etc/ipsec.d/certs/host_cert.pem
        right=192.168.0.5
        rightid=@host2
        auto=add
        authby=rsasig
        type=transport
        compress=no
```

Host2 (freebsd)

```
# $FreeBSD: releng/11.2/etc/sysctl.conf 112200 2003-03-13 18:43:50Z mux $
#
#  This file is read when going to multi-user and its contents piped thru
#  ``sysctl'' to adjust kernel values.  ``man 5 sysctl.conf'' for details.
#
# Uncomment this to prevent users from seeing information about processes that
# are being run under another UID.
#security.bsd.see_other_uids=0
# set to at least 16MB for 10GE hosts
kern.ipc.maxsockbuf=16777216

# set autotuning maximum to at least 16MB too
net.inet.tcp.sendbuf_max=16777216
net.inet.tcp.recvbuf_max=16777216

# enable send/recv autotuning
net.inet.tcp.sendbuf_auto=1
net.inet.tcp.recvbuf_auto=1

# increase autotuning step size
net.inet.tcp.sendbuf_inc=16384
net.inet.tcp.recvbuf_inc=524288

# set this on test/measurement hosts
net.inet.tcp.hostcache.expire=1

# Set congestion control algorithm to Cubic or HTCP
# Make sure the module is loaded at boot time - check loader.conf
# net.inet.tcp.cc.algorithm=cubic
net.inet.tcp.cc.algorithm=htcp
```

Host2 ipsec.conf

```
# ipsec.conf - strongSwan IPsec configuration file

# basic configuration
config setup
        charondebug="ike 4, knl 4, cfg 4"

conn %default
        ikelifetime=60m
        keylife=20m
        rekeymargin=3m
        keyingtries=1
        keyexchange=ikev2
        mobike=no

conn host-host

        left=192.168.0.5
        leftid=@host2
      leftcert=/usr/local/etc/ipsec.d/certs/host_cert.pem
        right=192.168.0.4
        rightid=@host1
        auto=add
        authby=rsasig
        type=transport
        compress=no
```

Comment: Have you invested some time on removing the cpu bottleneck by increasing parallelism? - https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Pcrypt - Don't know how it works on modern kernels, and it's been a long time i don't configure a strongswan/openswan based VPN.

Comment: After asking a colleague it looks like i didn't have aesni enabled on my OS.  I went ahead and did that but strongswan on the FreeBSD host doesn't have the aesni plugin enabled. I tried manually adding file in /usr/local/etc/strongswan.d/charon/aesni.conf and restarting the service but that didn't seem to do the trick...

Comment: After loading the aesni module on FreeBSD(`kldload aesni`), any vpn software that supports should use it. What about if your colleague uses `racoon` instead of Strongswan at the FreeBSD side, just for testing? It's the suggested software for IPSec at the FreeBSD Handbook - https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ipsec.html